# How to get the value of input element on blur of it?

Tags: html, jquery

I have a input box and a label. I want apply a specific style to the label when there is content in the box. For that I need to get the value typed in it on the blur event so that I can compare it. I tried to write

```
<input type="text />"
<label>something</label>
$('input').blur(function() {
    $('label').css('color','red');
    console.log($(this).val())
})
```

If there is something typed in the input box I should get that value printed in the console. But what I'm getting is an empty value to the console. The color is changing when blur but cannot get value.

Is there a way to get the value typed and use in the blur event.

Comment: Please note that `<input type="text />"` should be `<input type="text" />`. And you code works fine. try here https://jsfiddle.net/7swq9bpy/1/

Comment: you could use `keyup` function if you want the input to appear as soon as you type something - `blur` will only `console.log` once you click outside the input after finish typing.

Comment: Sorry for the typo. I wrote <input type="text" /> like this in my code but didn't work.

Comment: @ Gowthamss Have you checked the JS fiddle link @CarstenLøvboAndersen added for you. Its all working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `keyup()` and then check the value with `this.value`.

```
$('input').keyup(function() {   
  const valueToCompare = "someValue";
  if (this.value == valueToCompare) {
    $('label').css('color','red');  
  } 
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qu3w8jxc/1/